# Table named by a MySQL reserved word cannot be altered or dropped

Tags: mysql

Accidentally I named my table "RollUp" which is a reserved word in MySQL.

For some reason there was no error and the table had been successfully created.

Now I can SELECT, DESCRIBE etc. but I cannot ALTER, RENAME or DROP.

Backtick doesn't help.

How could I get rid of this table (either change its name or completely drop it)?

Comment: Try using double-quotes `"table name"` instead of backticks.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Dai That's a pretty odd suggestion. What would you accomplish by using double quotes with a semantic that can change, depending on the SQL mode? The backticks always enclose identifiers and are pretty much always the right choice.

Comment: @MikeLischke I suggested it because the ISO SQL specification requires double-quotes for escaping reserved identifiers, not backticks - and MySQL 8+ is much better at ISO SQL compliance than earlier versions - and I assume people working with MySQL today are using `ANSI_QUOTES` (because it's silly not to...). I don't know why backticks aren't working for the OP but I assumed it was worth a shot. That said, I'm not a MySQL expert - but as you work for Oracle do you know why backticks aren't working for the OP - or can reach out to someone internally who does know?

Comment: @Dai Did you read the answer the OP posted? It hasn't to do with quoting why the table couldn't be dropped. And for quoting: the documentation says that reserved words must be quoted and first mentions: [`The identifier quote character is the backtick (\`)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: I have no error creating and doropping this table too. Could you please provide the error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE rollup (i INT NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE rollup;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I did not close Python connection to the database.
Thank you and I am sorry for asking stupid question, it may be removed.